# Powershell SQL Server SMO - Failed to Enumerate Collection error

Tags: sql-server-2014, powershell

I have a weird problem with PowerShell and the Invoke-Sqlcmd when used in a ForEach block. In an nutshell, I've done this before many times and not really seen this.

I have a list of SQL Server instances in a database table, let's call it inst_list, and lets say it contains 3 instances: Inst1, Inst2 and Inst3. I'm populating an array called $instances, like this:

```
$instances = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $myserver `
-database $mydatabase -query "select name from inst_list") | 
select-object -expand name
```

Then in a ForEach block, I'm enumerating over the list and running Invoke-Sqlcmd, like this:

```
 foreach ($instance in $instances)
{
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $instance -database master -query "SELECT 1"
}
```

Simple enough right? However, I'm getting a `Failed to Enumerate Collection` error output, and alongside that another error which is `Can't Connect to Server Inst1 Inst2 Inst3`.

It's as if it's seeing my variable `$instances` as one large, long string than as a collection of instances to loop over.

Comment: When you say your table (inst_list) has 3 instances, you mean there are 3 rows - one for inst1, one for inst2 and one for inst3 - correct?

Comment: I ran your command as is (of course change servername, table name.  It runs perfect for me.  I am pulling from SQL server 10.0.2430.0 to pull servernames. Powershell 4.0.

Comment: Scott, that's correct

Comment: @Molenpad - I also ran your command (with simple changes) and it ran fine for me as well - what's in $instances (before the foreach) - is it a string or an array?

Comment: Ok - it seems to be a perms thing related to SMO on 3/70 servers. I should have mentioned earlier that there SMO is used as well as an invoke-sqlcmd. If I remove the SMO bit it works ok. Does use of SMO require specific permissions.

Comment: Replcace Invoke -Sqlcmd with a print statement Write-Host $instance. That will tell you if you have the right value or if it is a permission issue connecting to the servers.

Comment: @Molenpad this might help. Caution: it is an old post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898423/does-sql-server-smo-require-special-permissions-to-be-used